# buiding a dropdown with json

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, pug

**Requirement :**
I have a json response that I would like to transform to a `dropdown`. I'm using a jade template to handle the iteration but I'm having troubles getting the values. I'd like the sys_id be passed as a value on selecting the option(u_product_name) from the dropdown.

**JS**

```
result = //result is coming from API but this is what a console.log(result) shows
{ result: 
   [ 
     { sys_id: '7d950856',
       u_product_name: 'ACCESS' },
     { sys_id: '803279e1',
       u_product_name: 'AVAYA' },
     { sys_id: '87484c96',
       u_product_name: 'ADAMO' },
     { sys_id: 'b3b9001a',
       u_product_name: 'ADM' } 
   ]
}
```

Closest thing i've gotten was using `JSON strigify`, although that split each letter as a new option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this i hope it will work :**

**Html :**

```
<select id="items"></select>
```

**Script :**

```
 var data={ result: 
                   [ 
                     { sys_id: '7d950856',
                       u_product_name: 'ACCESS' },
                     { sys_id: '803279e1',
                       u_product_name: 'AVAYA' },
                     { sys_id: '87484c96',
                       u_product_name: 'ADAMO' },
                     { sys_id: 'b3b9001a',
                       u_product_name: 'ADM' } 
                   ]
    };

var elemArr = data.result;
var select = document.getElementById( 'items' );

for (options in elemArr) {
select.add( new Option( elemArr[options].u_product_name) );
}
```

**Working demo :** https://jsfiddle.net/rohitjindal/ndfv8cy0/

Answer (score 1):

Sample is

```
    var data={ result: 
       [ 
         { sys_id: '7d950856',
           u_product_name: 'ACCESS' },
         { sys_id: '803279e1',
           u_product_name: 'AVAYA' },
         { sys_id: '87484c96',
           u_product_name: 'ADAMO' },
         { sys_id: 'b3b9001a',
           u_product_name: 'ADM' } 
       ]
    }

    $.each(data.result, function (key, value) {

        $("#yourdropdownid").append($("<option></option>").val(value.sys_id).html(value.u_product_name));

    });
```